# Lua - как передать запрос дальше на бекенд

Tags: nginx, lua

Прошу помощи в настройке связки lua + nginx. Есть логика которая через lua скрипт парсит post запрос nginx для дальнейшей записи в лог (скрипт свою задачу делает). Есть бекенд на ларавеле.

Наcтройка nginx.conf

```
location / {

        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        lua_code_cache off;
        lua_need_request_body on;
        set $changed_request "";

        if ($request_method = POST)
        { 
            content_by_lua_file /usr/local/etc/nginx/lua/newlog.lua;

        } 
        }
```

Проблема в том что таким методом скрипт lua выступает бекендом и запрос циклиться на нем и дело к index.php даже не доходит. Каким образом настроить так что бы lua скрипт делал свою задачу и выступил что то вроде middleware делая реврайт на необходимый урл.
 Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Во-первых у вас не должно быть деректив `if` в `location`. Во-вторых, если я правильно понял, то вы ищете `nginx.location.capture`

Comment: Да вы абсолютно правы - я уже понял что это условие тут не уместно. Относительно своего вопроса переуточню. Мне необходимо запускать луа код независимо от бекенда, выступая в роли фильтра обработки HTTP-запроса. Повторюсь - скрипт работает и запускаеться.

Comment: решил проксированием